# Calling a SOAP method with PHP for a specific service

Tags: php, soap

Sorry to have to do this, but I'm getting no love from the people who run this particular webservice. I've never used SOAP before.

[Here's the method I'm trying to call](https://cwi.rezexchange.com:9991/Service.asmx?op=CwiRateDetails)

And here's the code I'm thinking should work

```
    public function soapTest(){

            echo "start <br />";
            use_soap_error_handler(true);
            $client = new SoapClient("https://cwi.rezexchange.com:9991/?wsdl");

                // here's the problem. What goes in the parenthesis?
            $result = $client->CwiRateDetails(????);

            echo($result);
            echo "<br /> end";

        }
```

Now I'm guessing this tells me what the parenthesis should contain.

```
POST /Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: cwi.rezexchange.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://hotelconcepts.com/CwiRateDetails"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <CwiRateDetails xmlns="http://hotelconcepts.com/">
      <PropertyCode>string</PropertyCode>
      <DateFrom>dateTime</DateFrom>
      <DateTo>dateTime</DateTo>
      <RatePlan>string</RatePlan>
      <RoomType>string</RoomType>
      <PromotionalRates>boolean</PromotionalRates>
    </CwiRateDetails>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My guess is that something like

```
$result = $client->CwiRateDetails($PCode, $DateFrom, $DateTo, $RatePlan, $RoomType, false);
```

Should work. But I don't know what the date format is, or what room types are or how to reference a rate plan.

Now. Before I go ape shit bannana bonkers over email with them, am I wrong in thinking there's a load more information they need to give me? Or is there some sort of SOAP trickery I can use to get that information from somewhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
$result = $client->CwiRateDetails(array(
    'PropertyCode'     => ...,
    'DateFrom'         => ...,
    'DateTo'           => ...,
    'RatePlan'         => ...,
    'RoomType'         => ...,
    'PromotionalRates' => ...,
));
```

You'll have to serialize your date-time-values in `DateFrom` and `DateTo` and the boolean value in `PromotionalRates` according to the  XML Schema specifications:

- [boolean](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#boolean): `true` = `'true'` or `1` and `false` = `'false'` or `0`
- [dateTime](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime): `YYYY-MM-DD`T`hh:mm:ss`Z for UTC or `YYYY-MM-DD`T`hh:mm:ss(+/-)hh:mm` for local-time including timezone information; timezone information is optional

Answer (score 1):

the date format is actually dateTime (which is a SOAP format type). I'm sure there is an example on the internet that converts a time() (or whatever) to a SOAP::dateTime field.

the information you need to connect is all there.. maybe you should read up on webservices first?

Answer (score 0):

Usualy it's associative array where keys are fields which you find in description, i.e. PropertyCode,DateFrom,DateTo etc for CwiRateDetails

so it would be something like

```
$client->CwiRateDetails(array("PropertyCode"=>"sdsd","DateFrom"=>"",......))
```

You can see details of every methods on this page: https://cwi.rezexchange.com:9991/ Just click on procedure's name and you will see it's parameters and it's responce.

Answer (score 0):

You are not wrong, IMO. There must be other SOAP calls to derive the information you need. Have you looked at [List Rate Types](https://cwi.rezexchange.com:9991/Service.asmx?op=CwiListRateTypes)? What about the list of methods [here](https://cwi.rezexchange.com:9991/)?