# SoapClient connection to SoapServer

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I need to connect to a SOAP Server from php, I read a lot of documentation, examples  and tutorials, but I still cannot make authentication to my server. I have done the work below:

```
 $agencyNumber = 7818619810;
    $fullTransmission = false;
    //$context = array('header' => 'Content-type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8');
    $params = array( 'agencyNumber'     => 7818619810, 'fullTransmission' => 0/*,$context*/);

    $client = new SoapClient("http://link/to/server?wsdl");
   $test =  $client->__getFunctions();
    var_dump($test );// returns the functions my supplier provides, as well __getTypes() gives a bunch of variable arrays ect..
    $response = $client->__soapCall('GetTransmissionTicket',array($params) );//line 16 which is mentioned on error print
    var_dump($response);
```

Even though I set `$context`, when I try to run, I get the error below:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Cannot process the
>   message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the
>   expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'. in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\xml\inc\connection_test.php:16 Stack trace: #0
>   [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('http://interfac...', '..//my-provider...', 1, 0) #1
>   C:..path..test.php(16): SoapClient->__soapCall('GetTransmission...',
>   Array) #2 {main} thrown in C:..path..test.php on line 16

The remote method I'm trying to call is called `GetTransmissionTicket` which takes two parameters, `(int)agencyNumber` and `fullTransmission`(bool)..

I want to emphasize that there are a lot of threads on this topic, some of which are really close to my question([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593623/how-to-make-a-php-soap-call-using-the-soapclient-class/11593827#11593827), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/777346/calling-a-soap-method-with-php-for-a-specific-service), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+soapclient) and so on ..), but I really couldn't solve the problem. Please give a hand..
Kind Regards..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example with soap and php can be

```
$url="your WSDL url";
$method = "Method you are calling";
$error=0;
$client = new SoapClient($url);

 try
  { 
    $info = $client->__call($method, array($param));
  } 
  catch (SoapFault $fault) 
 { 
    $error = 1; 
    errorReport($fault->faultcode,$fault->faultstring);
    die;
    /*echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Sorry,App Returne the following ERROR:'.$fault->faultcode."-".$fault->faultstring.'  We will now take you back to our homepage."); window.location = "'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'";</script> '; */

         }

     if($error==1)
      {
         $xml=$fault->faultstring;
     }else{
        $xml = $info;
     }
    return $xml;
```

Try implementing it and let me know. if it works for you.

Comment: thanks for your attention but undefined function errorReport. also i couldnt understand what you have tried to do. Is this a function or, what do you 'return' ?

Comment: Actuly this was a function created in my code i have selected the important part only.
Here errorReport is a SoapFault method which will give you the error if any occured while calling a wsdl 
I am returning a soap envelop responcse iff $error == 0 that means i got the method return values in $xml; 
Go through the code again line by line you will get to know ...
If u still have question .PLease feel free to ask.

Answer (score 10):

Try `$params = array( 'agencyNumber'     => 7818619810, 'fullTransmission' => false);`

instead of `$params = array( 'agencyNumber'     => 7818619810, 'fullTransmission' => 0);`

**OR**

Use `$client = new SoapClient("http://link/to/server?wsdl", array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_1));`

because
`application/soap+xml` is the content-type passed when using SOAP 1.2, `text/xml` is used with SOAP 1.1,

**Reference :** [how to change content-type of request?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1688239/1517293)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't the last line be **var_dump($response);** instead of **var_dump($client);**

Anyways, you can also try using this to get the result :

```
$response = $client->GetTransmissionTicket(array($params) );
var_dump($response);
```

Comment: yes it should be response, i editted thanks for warning. But again it gives error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'. in ...

Comment: I think then the problem is exactly the same as this - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5405874/1858648)
This is the answer according to this question - **The SOAP server you are using is not complaint with the 1.2 standard.**

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem by switching from SOAP 1.2 to SOAP 1.1:

```
$this->client = new SoapClient(
    $url,
    array(
        "trace" => TRUE,
        "exception" => 0,
        "soap_version" => SOAP_1_1,
        "cache_wsdl" => WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY,
        "local_cert" => 'mycert.pem',
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

may be little late but could help others. so here it goes:
`$params` is already an array so you don't have to use array($params) in

```
$response = $client->__soapCall('GetTransmissionTicket',array($params) );
```

instead use simple $params while calling.check it like this

```
$response = $client->GetTransmissionTicket($params);
```

also use `$client->__getTypes();` to verify params to be passed.
use catch to good effect to trace faultstringand faultactor.
at the end if still not getting solution check it with soapUI(a software).

Comment: I had solved the issue using nuSoap, but since on forums it is said nuSoap is not a prefered solusion, i didn't share my answer. Thanks.

Comment: unfortunatelly your solution hasn't done any thing, i have run my own(nuSoap) Solution while trying to try yours..

Comment: @İlhanÇetin Please can you post your solution

Comment: @Duli [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740576/soapclient-connection-to-soapserver/16830088?noredirect=1#answer-16830858) is my solution, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question so that it helps someone one day. I used nusoap and changed the encoding to utf-8. The code snippet is below:

```
require_once "nusoap.php";
$client = new nusoap_client("http://interface.--Serivce-Supplier-Link/Service.svc?wsdl", "wsdl");
$client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8';

$result = $client->call("GetTransmissionTicket", array( 'agencyNumber'     => 13155, 'fullTransmission' => false));
var_dump($result);
```

*Kind Regards*